# All custom fields are not working properly

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I was working on a wordpress site and I have used **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin. I have also used **Team Members** plugin and after adding team members the shortcode that was generated I have put that on the Team custom field. But it was not reflecting. I have checked source code, the section was missing there

Also, I have tried using the same shortcode on the other fields, that worked but it's not working on the team field

Here I am sharing the screenshot. https://www.screencast.com/t/4tyIpfCz3N

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Meet The Team</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            [tmm name="core-team"]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used the above code on the team field. On other fields it was working but it wasn't working only on that particular section

Any kind of help will be appreciatable

Comment: Kindly share the template code you are using to display these fields - https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/shortcodes-in-text-field/

Comment: these fields are displayed by plugin https://www.screencast.com/t/oNLF1pHfSaOw @essexboyracer

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question.

Comment: How can i post a code when I have used Plugins? @Rob

Comment: Is the code above in the ACF WYSIWYG field or is it in the php template? What code are you running in the PHP template?

Comment: in the field.. i am not running code in php template as i have used plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need to `get_field( 'team' )` in your template file, additionally you need to wrap this in `do_shortcode()`, as below:

`echo do_shortcode( get_field( 'team' ) );`

BUT there are lots of things wrong with how you are approaching this. You shouldn't be putting HTML in a WYSIWYG ACF field, they aren't built for that. Your HTML belongs in a template file. The point of ACF is to make things easier for end users to update and you have just complicated that by 1000% by forcing them to write HTML.

You don't even need to use your 'Team' ACF field for this section of what I presume is a single page website. Just put the below code into your page template (I'm assuming front-page.php). It will pull the team members directly from the Team plugin shortcode, bypassing ACF all together.

```
<h2>Core Team</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <?php echo do_shortcode( '[tmm name="8"]' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edited after code example by OP:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Meet The Team</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <?php echo do_shortcode( '[tmm name="core-team"]' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I did the same! I have put that code but it wasn't working

Comment: Right. But we didn't know that because you didn't post any reproducible code. Please post your code otherwise no-one here will be able to help you